# Issue with COM+DLL in IIS 6.0

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, com+

We have a COM+DLL in IIS 6 supporting an ASP classic Application. We have successfully debugged to the point that we know that the DLL is causing hangs in the worker process (a call to the object is never returned).  What configuration options are there for fixing this issue?

Comment: It would help to get a lot more details here. You might provide some specifics about what application you're working with, what your debugging showed, and what form of solution you're hoping for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution we found was to limit the amount of time COM+ will let a call run, and then  terminate it.

We found this event in the event log that gave it away:

> The average call duration has exceeded 10 minutes. If this is not the expected behavior, please see article 910904 in the Microsoft Knowledge Base at http://support.microsoft.com for details on how to use the COM+ AutoDump feature to automatically generate dump files and/or terminate the process if the problem occurs again.
>   Server Application ID: {20D49551-DF30-4A60-B553-CAD7B97F2153}
>   Server Application Instance ID:
>   {45DB1F97-8995-481C-94EE-CA891E446202}
>   Server Application Name: <-REDACTED->

Which lead us to this [kb](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910904/).

We then modified the settings at **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\COM3\AutoDump** 
according to the kb.  The issue still occurs, but now it doesn't hang up the whole server, only one user gets hung.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried running in IIS5 Compatability mode?

1. Right-click properties on the "Web Sites" node in the IIS Manager UI
2. Select the "Service" tab in the property page
3. There will be a checkbox controlling whether IIS6 runs "WWW service in IIS5 isolation mode" or not. Check it to have IIS6 run with IIS5 Worker Process Isolation Mode.